# How to handle simultaneous ajax responses using single ajax method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Method for handling ajax

```
function ajaxMethod(){
    return $.ajax({
        url: ajaxUrl,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSONP",
        jsonpCallback: ajaxCallback
    });
}
```

Calls to this method:

```
dD(ajaxMethod());
aA(ajaxMethod());
bB(ajaxMethod());
cC(ajaxMethod());
```

aa,bb,cc,dd method have

```
promise.success(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Now aA response is coming in bB function,,bb response in cc function and as simultaneous call is coming.
Also tried using async true nothing happens.
Any suggestions?

Comment: by default `async` will be set to true, since thats what `$.ajax({ .. }` was created for.

Answer (score 1):

With `jsonpCallback` you are telling jQuery to use a specific function name for the callback function (instead of generating a unique one), so each time you call it, you overwrite the previous function.

Just remove `jsonpCallback: ajaxCallback`.

---

While you are at it, remove `type: "POST",`, it is incompatible with JSONP.

Comment: I am hiting service call which has hardcoded callback function name so can't use use unique name that is generated by the jquery

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after.

This code is using the returned promise to wait for the result then passing the result to your other function.

```
ajaxMethod().success(function(response)
{
    dD(response);
});

ajaxMethod().success(function(response)
{
    aA(response);
});

ajaxMethod().success(function(response)
{
    cC(response);
});

ajaxMethod().success(function(response)
{
    dD(response);
});
```

Your aA, bB, cC and dD methods can now be:

```
function <insertname>(response)
{
    console.log(response);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want your request to come in the synchronous way, then try the following :

```
var callBack = $.Callbacks();

callBack.add(dD(ajaxMethod()));
callBack.add(aA(ajaxMethod()));
callBack.add(bB(ajaxMethod()));
callBack.add(cC(ajaxMethod()));
callBack.fire();
```

the above line of code will make sure the respective ajax call would get call.